# Сложности с подключением OpenGL к MVS 2017

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017

Попытка подключения происходила по инструкции с вот этого сайта http://rucodes.com/opengl-microsoft-visual-studio-c.html.
При компиляции предложенного на сайте кода (после выполнения всех описанных там ранее действий) вылезают две ошибки:

LNK1104 не удаётся открыть файл "glut32.lib"

MSB6006 "link.exe" завершилась с кодом 1104.

Может быть, файлы были не туда заброшены? Либы у меня лежат в C:\Program files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\lib

Comment: Что-то смущает меня инструкция валить стороннюю библиотеку в каталоги компилятора... Я бы поместил где-то в сторонке, и в проекте указал, откуда брать библиотеки и где искать заголовочные файлы. Ну не наш это метод :) - кидать заголовочные файлы к стандартным, и библиотеки куда-то туда же...

Comment: @Harry, а можно поподробнее о том, как это реализовать?

Comment: Что именно? Как положить файл в папку? :) Или как указать в свойствах проекта, где что искать? Первое - средствами Windows :), второе - зайдите в свойства проекта и посмотрите, что там и где; я так не помню навскидку. Но там все просто.